# Change bootstrap button size depending on screen width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to change both the size (e.g `btn-xs` to `btn-lg`) and the number of columns a bootstrap button spans, based on the width of the screen. The last part is not a problem, but how do I do the first part? Is there a way to inherit class and then do a media-query e.g

```css
@media only screen and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width:1024px) {

.my-button{
.btn-lg
    }    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey u could leverage selective display from bootstrap like below:

```
<div class="d-block d-sm-none">
    <div>
        <button class="btn-xs">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

The above one will only be visible on xs.
Refer https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/ for more combinations

Answer (score 0):

You can drop .btn-lg and .btn-sm. Just put a padding like p-2 and media query the font size based on screen size.

Answer (score 0):

Since button size resizes with text's `font-size`, why not use `vh`/`vw` for your button's text's `font-size`?